# Publishing .net core 5.0 into single exe file

Tags: c#

Can anybody help me.
I'm trying to publish my .net core console app into single file.

I'm using this command:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true
```

I'm expecting that it will create a single file. But still there's dll files:

```
clrcompression.dll
clrjit.dll
coreclr.dll
mscordaccore.dll
```

How I can fix it? I already search but that's the same result

Answer (score 12):

To bundle native libraries you need to specify the `IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract` flag.

So try running this `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#other-considerations

Comment: Alright this might be what I'm looking for. I'm gonna try later and I'll feedback

Answer (score 1):

To include the dotnet runtime dlls into your executable, you need to also use the `--self-contained` flag. So you can run `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true --self-contained true`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file

Comment: already tried it also. Still the same.

https://i.imgur.com/lNA0sIz.png

Comment: I have tried tried it and gavee the same result. @Anis's answer is right

Answer (score 0):

If using visual studio, go Build-> Publish [yourprojectname], edit the profile and check Produce single file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem but I found the answer by exploring the `dotnet publish` help menu. Use the following command `dotnet publish -r win-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true` this will embed the .dlls in the binary therefore in the publish folder will remain only a .pdb file which isn't necessary during runtime.