# How to use or replace ILMerge in Visual Studio project now that it is deprecated?

Tags: nuget, deprecated, ilmerge

I have an old VS project I am trying to compile. It used the ILMerge 3.0.41 Nuget package to put all of the application's dll's into a single .exe binary.

It seems that ILMerge has been deprecated. (https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge/)  While I do have one machine that apparently still has the old version on it, I can't get it to download and install the package on a new machine.

I'm not too familiar with how nuget packages work. Is there any way I can download it and manually include it in my project?

Failing that, is there something else I should be using besides this deprecated package?

Comment: Instead of ILMerge, if it is possible to upgrade the project to e.g. .NET 6.0, there is inbuilt support for combining into a single exe. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65134756/publishing-net-core-5-0-into-single-exe-file.

Comment: A package being deprecated doesn't prevent it from being downloaded, restored, installed, or used in any other way. It's just a notice for people maintaining their apps that their dependency isn't being maintained any longer, so if they're concerned about bug fixes or new features, that they might want to investigate other options.

Comment: https://github.com/gluck/il-repack